# Initialize the value and detect it when text is entered

Tags: java, android

My problem is 12 + 13 = 26. It first takes 1 and adds it to 12 so the result is 13. Then, it takes 13 and adds it to mresult which is 13. So it gives me wrong answer.
How do I know that user finishes typing, so I can initialize the value to number2?

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //CURRENT_ACTION = DEF_____________________________________________

            if((CURRENT_ACTION == DEF) && !textNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                number1 = Double.parseDouble(textNumber.getText().toString());
                mResult = number1;
                textResult.setText(String.valueOf(mResult));

            }

            //CURRENT_ACTION = ADD______________________________________________

            else if(CURRENT_ACTION == ADD && !textNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                number2 = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                mResult = mResult + number2;
                textResult.setText(String.valueOf(mResult));
            }


            //CURRENT_ACTION = SUB__________________________________________________

            else if(CURRENT_ACTION == SUB && !textNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                number2 = Double.parseDouble(textNumber.getText().toString());
                mResult = mResult - number2;
                textResult.setText(String.valueOf(mResult));

            }
        }
    });

 buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CURRENT_ACTION = ADD;
            textNumber.setText(null);

        }
    });

  buttonSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          CURRENT_ACTION = SUB;
          textNumber.setText(null);

      }
  });
```

Comment: Instead of trying to know when the user has finished, you can try to not store the result. Since you do not remember the precedent result, when the text goes from 1 to 13, your code redo the whole calculation : 12 + 13 and not old result + 13.

Comment: But f i don't store the value after typing 13 for example i press + and 14, then calculation is wrong again.

Comment: mmh okay, was unclear that you can enter more than 2 numbers... I'll try to update my answer to face this. Could you add the code where you modify `CURRENT_ACTION` I think a solution is somwhere here

Comment: i have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your code I suppose your EditText `textNumber` is used to enter everything. First you enter the first number and this number is displayed in the result TextView. Then you enter the sign `+` and `CURRENT_ACTION` is set to `ADD`. Then you enter the second number and you expect the result textview to display the result.

In your code you store the first number in three places :

- as text in the result TextView
- In the variable number1
- In the variable mResult

One is not necessary (hint : it's mresult)

You're problem is that you modify and reuse mResult. So you do not add first number to second number but temporary result with second number.

When you are in the case `ADD` get the first number from the variable `number1` (that won't be modified) and add the second number that you get from the EditText. Then store the result directly in the resultTextView (mResult is still not useful).

```
   @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //CURRENT_ACTION = DEF_____________________________________________

            if((CURRENT_ACTION == DEF) && !textNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                //store the first number
                number1 = Double.parseDouble(textNumber.getText().toString());
                //display current result : number1
                textResult.setText(String.valueOf(mResult));

            }

            //CURRENT_ACTION = ADD______________________________________________

            else if(CURRENT_ACTION == ADD && !textNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                //store second number
                number2 = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                // display second + first number as result
                textResult.setText(String.valueOf(number1 + number2));
            }


        }
    });
```

---

In the case you want a third number to be added. The code where you change `CURRENT_ACTION` has to be modified. When the user enter a `+` in your editText, you define `CURRENT_ACTION`to be set to `ADD`. Here you could add some code that will get the current result and store it as number1.

```
buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CURRENT_ACTION = ADD;
            textNumber.setText(null);
            //get the result and store it as the first number
            //then we will add the second number
            // that will be get from the other part of the code
            //to this first number
            number1 = Double.parseDouble(textResult.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

In this case storing the first value (when you are in case `DEF`) to number1 becomes useless cause it will be stored to number1 later when user will press the + button.

Comment: But if i add a third number let's say 20, how can i calculate the result?

Comment: @Gamer89 Glad to help :). BTW : In the case of more than 2 numbers, storing the first one to number1 in the TextChangeListener becomes useless cause it will be stored later when user will press a button (See my edit)